# How to access the nested objects in Prisma

Tags: reactjs, next.js, prisma

I use Prisma to generate data types.

```
model artworks {
  id            String          @id @default(dbgenerated("uuid_generate_v4()")) @db.Uuid
  title         String          @db.VarChar(255)
  artistid      String          @db.Uuid
  description   String?
  dataadded     DateTime?       @default(now()) @db.Time(6)
  isavailable   Boolean?        @default(true)
  imageurl      String          @db.VarChar(500)
  artworkimages artworkimages[]
  users         users           @relation(fields: [artistid], references: [id], onDelete: NoAction, onUpdate: NoAction, map: "fk_artistid")
}

model artworkimages {
id          String    @id(map: "artworkimage_pkey") @default(dbgenerated("uuid_generate_v4()")) @db.Uuid
  artworkid   String    @db.Uuid
  url         String    @db.VarChar(255)
  name        String?   @db.VarChar(255)
  createddate DateTime? @default(now()) @db.Timestamp(6)
  artworks    artworks  @relation(fields: [artworkid], references: [id], onDelete: NoAction, onUpdate: NoAction, map: "artworkimage_artworkid_fkey")
}
```

Here is the method to get artwork with images

```
export async function getArtwork(id: string): Promise<artworks | null> {  
  try {
    const artwork = await prisma.artworks.findUnique({
      where: { id },
      include: {
        artworkimages: true,
      }
    });
    return artwork;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Failed to fetch artwork:', error);
    throw new Error('Failed to fetch artwork.');
  }
}
```

When I try to access the `artwork.artworkimages` , it errors out saying

> Property 'artworkimages' does not exist on type '{ id: string; title:
> string; artistid: string; description: string | null; dataadded: Date
> | null; isavailable: boolean | null; imageurl: string; }'.

How can I get access to it?